Unable to Format as JSON text - Must Use Alias to the unnamed column or Table in Azure Data Factory
I have a copy activity in Azure Data Factory that uses the following query
@concat('SELECT *, LOWER(CONVERT(VARCHAR(64), HASHBYTES(''SHA2_256'',(SELECT * FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES)), 2)) AS signature FROM [', pipeline().parameters.Domain, '].[', pipeline().parameters.TableName, ']')

When I execute the copy activity I get the following error:

Operation on target Copy Table to Lake failed: Failure happened on 'Source' side. 'Type=Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=Must specify table to select from.
Column expressions and data sources without names or aliases cannot be formatted as JSON text using FOR JSON clause. Add alias to the unnamed column or table.,Source=Framework Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider,'

The copy activity is as follows:

Sample Dataset is a follows:
==========================================================================================================================================================================================================================
|         CountryName          |         CountryISO2          |         CountryISO3          |         SalesRegion          |         CountryFlag          |         FlagFileName         |         FlagFileType         |
==========================================================================================================================================================================================================================
|           Belgium            |          BE                  |          10                  |             EMEA             |             null             |             null             |             a                |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|           Germany            |          DE                  |          deletedupd          |             EMEA             |             null             |             null             |             c                |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|            Italy             |          IT                  |          ITA                 |             EMEA             |             null             |             null             |             d                |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|            Spain             |          ES                  |          Updated             |             EMEA             |             null             |             null             |             e                |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|        United Kingdom        |          GB                  |          GBR                 |             EMEA             |             null             |             null             |             f                |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|        United States         |          US                  |          USA                 |        North America         |             null             |             null             |             g                |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|           Scotland           |          SC                  |          SCO                 |           Britanny           |             null             |             null             |             z                |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|            Kenya             |          KY                  |          KEN                 |            Africa            |             null             |             null             |             h                |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|           Finland            |          FL                  |          FIN                 |            Finny             |             null             |             null             |             i                |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Sample output should look like the following:
=========================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
|        CountryName         |        CountryISO2         |        CountryISO3         |        SalesRegion         |        CountryFlag         |        FlagFileName        |        FlagFileType        |         signature          |
=========================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
|          Belgium           |         BE                 |         10                 |            EMEA            |            null            |            null            |            a               |a8a765cbe18b0956eda8d0cccf77|
|                            |                            |                            |                            |                            |                            |                            |8e9aae302a21b397d2a1c88b61ff|
|                            |                            |                            |                            |                            |                            |                            |          0b680bc6          |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|          Germany           |         DE                 |         deletedupd         |            EMEA            |            null            |            null            |            c               |1232b1bd91d14a87ed830f770d74|
|                            |                            |                            |                            |                            |                            |                            |cd8cabb871535c4c2b7ff5bcb873|
|                            |                            |                            |                            |                            |                            |                            |          fa80d851          |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|           Italy            |         IT                 |         ITA                |            EMEA            |            null            |            null            |            d               |584cf66de2f4af9eb4dbfebefea8|
|                            |                            |                            |                            |                            |                            |                            |08b1b4e6a35787fcac1061de88cf|
|                            |                            |                            |                            |                            |                            |                            |          b79856df          |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|           Spain            |         ES                 |         Updated            |            EMEA            |            null            |            null            |            e               |9147f93453c0c35324e104b1d1ca|
|                            |                            |                            |                            |                            |                            |                            |5750991de30cfda14c2e9ea8b916|
|                            |                            |                            |                            |                            |                            |                            |          c53d71a5          |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|       United Kingdom       |         GB                 |         GBR                |            EMEA            |            null            |            null            |            f               |76ac23d2a4ee9778791a4cb6f244|
|                            |                            |                            |                            |                            |                            |                            |13e4e0523f65e233b691c548bdb7|
|                            |                            |                            |                            |                            |                            |                            |          70bf0613          |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|       United States        |         US                 |         USA                |       North America        |            null            |            null            |            g               |e1c65ae69af6fdf75e0222ce6dba|
|                            |                            |                            |                            |                            |                            |                            |e312298bf765eb95f3acf1bf2603|
|                            |                            |                            |                            |                            |                            |                            |          22fc161b          |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|          Scotland          |         SC                 |         SCO                |          Britanny          |            null            |            null            |            z               |075fba3109e831d879df282fcadb|
|                            |                            |                            |                            |                            |                            |                            |36b370d28a62c75df2f71b9ee889|
|                            |                            |                            |                            |                            |                            |                            |          1c335a5c          |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|           Kenya            |         KY                 |         KEN                |           Africa           |            null            |            null            |            h               |222e9d81e47954d14e4c5a91b066|
|                            |                            |                            |                            |                            |                            |                            |788ac06ce5ea2c80cf75ec00e3cf|
|                            |                            |                            |                            |                            |                            |                            |          28e7b138          |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|          Finland           |         FL                 |         FIN                |           Finny            |            null            |            null            |            i               |87558fedd73139b13b7a969fe2ee|
|                            |                            |                            |                            |                            |                            |                            |544e731bab3e4607e4732a03ab08|
|                            |                            |                            |                            |                            |                            |                            |          ea96fbe8          |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

The MS SQL query that I used to get the sample output was as follows:
SELECT T.*, LOWER(CONVERT(VARCHAR(64), HASHBYTES('SHA2_256',(SELECT T.* FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES)), 2)) AS signature FROM Data.Country AS T;

I just modified it to make it work in ADF. Therefore, I don't understand why it's not possible to generate a hash for each field if I'm able to make it work in SQL Server

A markdown table, rather than code fenced/block pseudo tables would be far more readable here.


The above error says you are missing the table name while using JSON PATH.
As per the MSDoc,

You need to mention the table name from which you want extract the JSON.

So, the original SQL query should look like this if the table name is mytable1 and schema name dbo.
SELECT  *, LOWER(CONVERT(VARCHAR(64), HASHBYTES('SHA2_256',(SELECT  *  FROM [dbo].[mytable1] FOR  JSON  PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES)), 2)) AS  signature  FROM [dbo].[mytable1];

You need to modify your ADF pipeline expression as shown below to avoid the above error.
@concat('SELECT *, LOWER(CONVERT(VARCHAR(64), HASHBYTES(''SHA2_256'',(SELECT * FROM [',pipeline().parameters.Domain,'].[',pipeline().parameters.TableName,'] FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES)), 2)) AS signature FROM [', pipeline().parameters.Domain, '].[', pipeline().parameters.TableName, ']')


Output with Hash column:

Here, you need to note that the JSON PATH will create the same JSON of all columns and rows for all the rows so the Hash value for every row will be same.
Based on your output, it seems like you want to get the Hash value for each row in a new column. You can try SQL queries for concatenating all column values as mentioned in this SO answer by @Kaf and pass it to Hash function. But your data involves null values which are needed to be convert to strings before concatenating. But during the conversion also, it may require you to hardcode the column names.
So, here if your source and sink are not an on-prem, you can try ADF dataflow as a workaround instead of a copy activity to achieve your requirement. After adding your source, you can use the expression sha2(256,columns()) in the derived column transformation to create the new required column.

Result with different Hash:

Add your target dataset as sink and run the dataflow with a Dataflow activity from the pipeline.

Hi @Rakesh, there were no errors, however the signature is the exact same hash number for every field. If you take a look at my sample output, you will see that I get a different signature for each field, whereas you solution produces the output df21cd72262b5b6a53c8f66a8caa3b53ea902ba820d217e92f1c0b638889d204 for each field

Hi @Rakesh, unfortunately we don't use DataFlows at our office.

Yeah, as I said the JSON PATH creates a JSON of all columns and rows from which the hash value will be same for all rows. If you don't use dataflows, then you can try SQL query approaches from the SO answer that I have provided.

I updated the question to show the MS SQL that I used to successfully get the output on SQL Server. So, I'm confused as to why I can't get the same output with ADF....

What is the SQL server version? I will try to check from my end.

It's SQL Server Version 20
